# How to refresh specific label by using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I am trying to update a label every 5 seconds by using AJAX and interval, but actually it only works if I manually hit the refresh button. Without reloading the page the value is not changed.

I am using Webforms.

#### Client side:

JavaScript:

```
    setInterval(function () {
        function GetStatus() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "RunningConsolePage.aspx/GetStatus",
                data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            $("#<%=lblStatus.Text=GetStatus()%>")
        }
    }, 5);
```

HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnQArun" Text="QA" OnClick="btnQArun_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info btnSize" OnClientClick="Confirm('QA')" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text="Status" runat="server"/>
```

#### Server side:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string GetStatus()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 11)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }
```

Comment: Does it also cause this problem when using `ClientIDMode="Static"` and  changing `function OnSuccess(response) {` body to: 

`$('#<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').html(response)`?

I am unsure why you are using `GetStatus()` in between `<% ... %>` because that would only execute once when the page is first loaded, and you don't seem to be using the response data received in the OnSuccess response param.

Answer (score 1):

So put your methods out of interval, and then call it in interval. Also it is in miliseconts so 5 does not mean 5 seconds it does 5 miliseconds.

```
<script>
    setInterval(GetStatus, 5000);

function GetStatus() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "RunningConsolePage.aspx/GetStatus",
                data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            $("#<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>").text(response.d);
        }
</script>
```

Tip: 1000 ms = 1 second.

Also check out the selector in OnSuccess method it was wrong. Change it and it will work.

Also find more usefull information here: https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Cheers,